# Use Chrome extension to unbind click events?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, unbind

I'm trying to make an extension that unbinds a click event added by the website itself.

The website uses jQuery, which would make this insanely simple:

```
jQuery('a[rel]').unbind('click');
```

The problem is that my extension (using "content_scripts") can't access the website's jQuery object and therefore doesn't have the event functions to unbind. I can include a jQuery in my extension, but that wouldn't help, because jQuery stores 'data' in the jQuery object (not in the DOM elements). My jQuery will not have those events stored.

Is there another way? It doesn't have to be pretty. Maybe without "content_scripts"?

Comment: Can your extension inject a script into the page that does what you need?

Comment: Pointy, I could, but than I'd need an external script saved somewhere on the internet. I'd like it be just the `.crx`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var unbind_event_listeners = function (node) {
    var parent = node.parentNode;
    if (parent) {
        parent.replaceChild(node.cloneNode(true), node);
    } else {
        var ex = new Error("Cannot remove event listeners from detached or document nodes");
        ex.code = DOMException[ex.name = "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR"];
        throw ex;
    }
};
```

Just call `unbind_event_listeners(a_node)` to unbind any listeners from a node. This will work on every node in the document except `document` itself. As for `window`, you're out of luck. `unbind_event_listeners(document.documentElement)` should remove most event listeners attached to nodes in the document.

In the case of `a[rel]`, you'd want to do this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("a[rel]"), i = nodes.length;
while (i--) {
    unbind_event_listeners(nodes.item(i));
}
```

Comment: The function is a little overkill, but `el.parentNode.replaceChild(el.cloneNode(true), el);` does the trick beautifully! This answer is going in the favourites! =) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't need to be pretty and you're okay with doing things slightly hack-like, this should forcefully unbind every click listener bound to that element:

```
var el = document.querySelector('a[rel]');
el.onclick = function() {};
el.addEventListener = function() {};
```

or for every element:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel]')).forEach(function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {};
  el.addEventListener = function() {};
});
```

**EDIT:** You could maybe do something even uglier and have a content script run at "document_start" and do:

```
Element.prototype.addEventListener = (function() {
  var real = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
  return function(ev) {
    if (ev === 'click' && this.tagName === 'A' && this.hasAttribute('rel')) {
      console.log('try again, jquery!');
    } else {
      return real.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Actually that doesn't work. I think the only way to unbind a listener is with `HTMLElement.removeEventListener` and for that you need the initial event/function/callback/handler (which is stored in unreachable `window.jQuery`).

Comment: This just prevents binding new event listeners. I don't see anywhere where it *unbinds* event listeners.